# What is the best way to flush logger object in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js

My app is an API that stores log events of the requests that it receives. The custom logger object periodically writes the log events to a database, based on a timer or when the queue size reaches the max size. I want to flush this object's event log queue when the app is shut down, either because of a fatal error or redeployment. I'm using express and the native https modules to create the API server. I think I can flush the log in the server's error listener and the server's close callback, but how do I reference the logger object that is scoped to a different script in the project? I've looked into using global variables, but this seems to be highly discouraged, so is there a better alternative for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an [event listener on the `process` object](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_events), which is available globally in node. You will need to experiment with which event event to listen for to make sure it's consistently triggered and you're able to perform the work you want to do. The [signal events](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events) are likely your best bet since the `exit` event doesn't allow you to perform async tasks like flushing a